# Serving Django + React on same nginx server

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, progressive-web-apps, digital-ocean

I have a React PWA frontend and a Django backend (plus admin) that I want to serve on the same Digital Ocean droplet using nginx. In the past, I simply served the built index.html through a Django view, but that can be somewhat slow and doesn't seem to enable the PWA features. Any ideas how to configure nginx for that? Thanks.

Edit:
The nginx configuration so far:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name something_something;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/antoni4040/KDP/KDP_website;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/antoni4040/KDP/KDP_website;
    }


    location /admin/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /api/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }


    location / {
        root /var/www/build;
    }
}
```

Seems to work this time, but no PWA. What do I need to change?

Comment: What have you got configured/tried so far?

Comment: Added the nginx config.

Comment: On the droplet are the react build files under /var/www/build ?

Comment: Yes. Something is not working right with the service_worker for some reason. Are there special instructions for nginx?

Comment: The tutorial with exactly what you want https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/